# Swift - Coordinate is unavailable: APIs deprecated as of iOS 7

Tags: swift, annotations, mapkit, mkannotation

I'm trying to iterate through an array of annotations by getting by `self.mapView.annotations`.

The issue I'm having is that i'm getting an error because **Coordinate is unavailable: APIs deprecated as of iOS 7 and earlier are unavailable to Swift**.

Any ideas how I can fix this? I have a look at the iOS developer library but I couldn't find any way of getting the coordinate for each annotation.

```
var zoomRect:MKMapRect = MKMapRectNull;

for (index,annotation) in enumerate(self.mapView.annotations) {
    var annotationPoint:MKMapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate)
    var pointRect:MKMapRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x, annotationPoint.y, 0.1, 0.1);
    zoomRect = MKMapRectUnion(zoomRect, pointRect);
}

self.mapView.setVisibleMapRect(zoomRect, animated: true)
```

The main idea for this code is to center the map so that users will be able to see all the annotations. I got this code in Objective C (another question from SO) and converted it to Swift but still having no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `annotations` property of `MKMapView` returns `[AnyObject]!`
and `AnyObject` does not have a `coordinate` property.
You have to cast to an `[MKAnnotation]` array:

```
var zoomRect = MKMapRectNull
for annotation in self.mapView.annotations as [MKAnnotation] {
    let annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate)
    let pointRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x, annotationPoint.y, 0.1, 0.1)
    zoomRect = MKMapRectUnion(zoomRect, pointRect)
}
```

(The explicit type annotation in your code are not necessary, and the variables
inside the loop are in fact constants, so you can declare them with `let`.)

Note that you could replace the for-loop by a reduce operation:

```
let zoomRect = reduce(self.mapView.annotations as [MKAnnotation], MKMapRectNull) {
    rect, annotation in
    let annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate)
    let pointRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x, annotationPoint.y, 0.1, 0.1)
    return MKMapRectUnion(rect, pointRect)
}
```

Comment: That's right! I was focusing on that error and was trying to find an alternative of `annotation.coordinate` but what you said makes sense! Thank you!