# 'polyline' is unvailable: APIs deprecated as iOS 7 and earlier are unavailable in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkpolyline

Trying to get the route from A to B and plot over the mapView, but complier says **'polyline' is unavailable: APIs deprecated as of iOS7 and earlier are unavailable in Swift**

saw a similar thread here: [How to use MKPolylineView in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24798737/how-to-use-mkpolylineview-in-swift), but in this case it is 'polyline' that does not work, not other attributes.

Any thoughts on workaround?

Thanks!

```
var req: MKDirectionsRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()
req.setSource(MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: start, addressDictionary: nil)))
req.setDestination(MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: dest, addressDictionary: nil)))
var dir: MKDirections = MKDirections(request: req)
dir.calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler ({
    (response: MKDirectionsResponse?, error: NSError?) in

if let routes = response?.routes{
     for route in routes{
         println(route.polyline)
         self.mapView.addOverlay(route.polyline)  // <- this line gives the error
     }
}
})
```

Comment: Which version of Xcode? Are you sure its up to date?

Comment: 6.1 6A1052d. is it too old already?

Comment: Similar issue as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27195494/swift-coordinate-is-unavailable-apis-deprecated-as-of-ios-7: `routes` has to be cast to `[MKRoute]`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Martin R, casting to MKRoute does the trick